# sonar maven analysis only picks .java file

Tags: maven, groovy, sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

I am trying to run a sonar maven analysis on my multilanguage project which contains many languages like *.java, *.groovy, *.js etc. I have installed all the languages plugin in my sonar and configured my pom `sonar.sources` parameter as `src/main,src/test` but still it picks up only java files. In the console output. 
I get the following lines in the console indicating that it only scans the folders with pattern `src/main/java` and `src/test/java`

```
[INFO] [05:13:57.140] -------------  Scan myapp
[INFO] [05:13:57.140] Load module settings
[INFO] [05:13:57.187] Initializer FindbugsMavenInitializer
[INFO] [05:13:57.187] Initializer FindbugsMavenInitializer (done) | time=0ms
[INFO] [05:13:57.187] Base dir: C:\myapp
[INFO] [05:13:57.187] Working dir: C:\myapp\target\sonar
[INFO] [05:13:57.187] Source paths: pom.xml, src/main/java
[INFO] [05:13:57.187] Test paths: src/test/java
```

I am currently using SonarQube 5.1, Java 7u80

Note: If analysis is done using Sonar Runner, It scans all the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it was a multi module project, I had to include the properties `sonar.sources` and `sonar.tests` in the parent module's `pom.xml` file.

```
<properties>
    <sonar.sources>pom.xml,src/main,src/test</sonar.sources>
    <sonar.tests></sonar.tests>
</properties>
```

`sonar.tests` parameter is empty since it is incompatible with Maven.

Comment: Strange: sonar.tests seems to be working great for me (in SonarQube 4.5.5).  When I do sonar.tests (with "src/test") alongside sonar.sources (with "pom.xml,src/main"), I get a "Unit test success" box with a summary of the tests that have been run (and the test code does not get included in the overall analysis).  When I just include "src/test" in sonar.sources and leave sonar.tests blank, the tests get lumped in with the overall source code.

Answer (score 2):

Since SonarQube 4.2, it is possible to run an analysis on a multi-language project. To do so, the `sonar.language property` just has to be removed. Conversely, if for some reason you want to perform a single language-only analysis, make sure `sonar.language` is specified.

By default the sonar.sources property is set to the value of the Maven sourceDirectory property (by default it is `src/main/java`) plus `pom.xml` (and also `src/main/webapp` is automatically added for war modules). Therefore, for a multi-language project, the property usually has to be overridden to: `sonar.sources=src/main,pom.xml`.

Comment: `<properties><sonar.host.url>http://localhost:9000</sonar.host.url><sonar.jdbc.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar</sonar.jdbc.url><sonar.jdbc.username>sonar</sonar.jdbc.username><sonar.jdbc.password>sonar</sonar.jdbc.password><sonar.jdbc.driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</sonar.jdbc.driver><sonar.sources>src/main,src/test</sonar.sources></properties>` this is the current configuration in my pom.xml and does not have `sonar.language` property set.

Comment: first thing first.
1. do you have sonar server running ?
2. have you specified all sonar properties within sonar.properties file(like sonar web host, port , database , database credentials)
3. within your POM.xml you dont have to specify all these properties.

for your reference please refere pom.xml:https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/multi-language/multi-language-java-javascript-maven

Comment: 1. yes 2. when i am not using sonar runner, why should i have sonar.properties file? 3. this is a multi module project so I found it easy specifying these properties in pom.xml